# Javascript .find() How can I find and return all user names?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, find

I am learning Meteor right now and want get all the user names
I tried this: `Meteor.users.find({}, {"name" : 1}).fetch()`
and many variations of this. I always just get the whole object in MongoDB. But I just want to get all the clean usernames! How is that possible?
I googled and googled but dont understand anything :(

Comment: What exactly you can not understand?

Answer (score 2):

You are kind of close, on the right track at least. Here's how I would do it.

For starters, `name` is not a default field and usually this is intended to be placed in the `profile` subdocument of the user document. Like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "FkYj9MkLY2TmcDf7w",
    "emails" : [  
        {  "address" : "your@email.com",  "verified" : false } 
    ], 
    "profile" : { 
        "name" : "Bob Loblaw",
        "position" : "Attorney at law"
    }
}
```

FYI I've omitted typical password and services related details in the above example for brevity.

To retrieve the name you do this:

```
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
    'users': function() {
        return Meteor.users.find({});
    }
});
```

Then to display the names in your template:

```
{{#each users}}
    {{profile.name}}
{{/each}}
```

If you want to access the names within JavaScript rather than a template:

```
var users = Meteor.users.find({}).fetch();
_.each(users, function(user) {
    if(user.profile.name)
        console.log(user.profile.name);
});
```

So you can access document fields generally using dot notation:

```
Meteor.users.findOne({}).profile.name
```

Note that it's usually a good idea to check if the query returns a result before accessing a field (as shown above).

Lastly, there is a way to retrieve all users who have a name set and exclude those who don't.

```
Meteor.users.find({'profile.name': {$exists: true}})
```

One last thing to note is that the `'profile.name'` is in quotes because the field name includes a `.`. This also shows you how to access a subdocument field using dot notation within the query itself.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I tried it with the direct Javascript one. There I get the error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'user.profile.name'), but this: Meteor.users.findOne({}).profile.name really works how I imagined it. Is there no simple command for finding all?

Comment: Nps, sorry about the error. That was because a cursor was returned. I added fetch() to return an array.

You'll always have to iterate over an array or cursor to do something with each user name, see the answer from @Trever Faden. His approach returns directly an array of names without the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. As per the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find), the find method accepts two parameters - the selector and an options object.

To just return the name attribute, you'd do the following:

```
Meteor.users.find({},{fields:{'name':1, _id: 0}}).fetch()
```